# Members of $SL(2, 4)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I am attempting to automate a process for calculating members of the special linear group for a finite field (SL(n, f)). I have the following entries

```
┌ 0₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 2₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 1₄ ┐
└ 1₄ 0₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 0₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 2₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 0₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 2₄ ┘

┌ 1₄ 2₄ ┐  ┌ 2₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 1₄ ┐
└ 3₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 2₄ ┘  └ 2₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 0₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 2₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 0₄ ┘

┌ 1₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 2₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 2₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 3₄ ┐
└ 3₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 0₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 0₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 0₄ ┘  └ 2₄ 1₄ ┘

┌ 0₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 2₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 2₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 3₄ ┐
└ 3₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 2₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 0₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 0₄ ┘

┌ 1₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 2₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 2₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 0₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 2₄ ┐
└ 2₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 2₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 0₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 0₄ ┘  └ 2₄ 1₄ ┘

┌ 2₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 0₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 2₄ ┐  ┌ 0₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 2₄ 1₄ ┐
└ 1₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 0₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 0₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 2₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 1₄ ┘

┌ 3₄ 2₄ ┐  ┌ 0₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 2₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 0₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 1₄ ┐
└ 1₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 3₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 2₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 2₄ ┘

┌ 1₄ 3₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 1₄ ┐  ┌ 1₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 0₄ ┐  ┌ 3₄ 2₄ ┐  ┌ 0₄ 3₄ ┐
└ 0₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 0₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 2₄ 1₄ ┘  └ 2₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 2₄ 3₄ ┘  └ 1₄ 1₄ ┘
```

However I have only found 48 members. I am expecting 60, so what 12 are missing? Are there any incorrect ones in the existing bunch?

Comment: By $\operatorname{SL}(2,4)$, do you mean 2x2 matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or with elements in $\mathbb{F}_4$, the field with $4$ elements?. Because if it's the second, note that $\mathbb{F}_4$ has characteristic $2$, so matrices like $diag(3,1)$ are also a member of the group

Comment: The finite field with four elements is not the same as the integers mod $4$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @DerekHolt, I agree, and do suspect that the questioner has slipped into thinking, as have many, that $\mathbb Z/4$ is the field with $4$ elements...

Comment: Aha. Thanks @DerekHolt. I also mistakenly thought the poster asked about $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ instead of the field with four elements.

Comment: @DerekHolt ah yes. I think $Z_n$ is the same as $\mathbb{F}_n$ for n prime **but** 4 is not prime. (which is why I was confused because my attempts for $Sl(2,2)$ and $Sl(2,3)$ had the same order for what I found online).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to brute force enumerate them, go through all $4^4$ matrices and throw out those with $ad-bc\neq 1$.  You could also label them by their minimal polynomial ($x^2-\text{tr} M+\det M$, so just by trace in this case).  I think the main problem is confusion about $\mathbb{F}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

[$\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,3\}$ has a zero divisor $2$ which you seem to be avoiding which makes me think you're working over this ring instead of the field with four elements.  Another answer covers this case.]

You can take $\mathbb{F}_4=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)=\{0,1,x,x+1\}$ with multiplication
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&0&1&x&x+1\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0\\
1&&1&x&x+1\\
x&&&x+1&1\\
x+1&&&&x\end{array}
$$
In general, $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has order
$$
(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q^n-q^{n-1})
$$
which is $q-1$ cosets of $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ (under the determinant map), so
$$
|SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|=\frac{1}{q-1}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^i).
$$

---

Here's a Python script to enumerate them, with the binary rep convention $(0,1,2,3)=(0,1,x,x+1)$:

```
mt = [[0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,3],[0,2,3,1],[0,3,1,2]]

elts = [0,1,2,3]

sl = []

for a in elts:
    for b in elts:
        for c in elts:
            for d in elts:
                if mt[a][d]^mt[b][c] == 1:
                    sl.append((a,b,c,d))

print(len(sl))
for m in sl:
    print(m)
```

Comment: Ah yes I see why my attempt with $(ad-bc) \% 4 == 1$ is invalid for $\mathbb{F}_4$. However it would be valid for n = 2,3,5,7,11 as they are prime? Using `mt` is clever idea.

Comment: Also you can `from itertools import product` then change `for a,b,c,d in product(elts, repeat=4)` to prevent the nested for loops (and should make testing 3x3 matricies easier).

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $\mathbb{F}_4^4$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{F}_4)$. The next code generates all vectors of $\mathbb{F}_4^4$ how list:

```
def change_bass(number,bass, n):
 if number == 0:
  return [0 for i in range(n)]

 binary_list = []
 while number > 0:
  bit = number % base
  binary_list.append(bit)
  number //= bass
 while len(binary_list)<n:
  binary_list.append(0)
 return binary_list
```

Now all vectors are list in range $4^4$:

```
import numpy as np

n = 4
q = 4
numbers = q**n
FF = []
for number in range(numbers):
 lista = change_bass(number,q,n)
 FF.append(lista)
SL = []
for vector in FF:
 matrix = np.reshape(vector,(2,2))
 det =  np.linalg.det(matrix)
  if det in [1,3]:
   SL.append(matrix)
```

The result is:

```
[[1, 0],
 [0, 1]],

[[1, 1],
 [0, 1]],

[[1, 2],
 [0, 1]],

[[1, 3],
 [0, 1]],

[[1, 0],
[1, 1]],

[[2, 1],
 [1, 1]],

[[1, 0],
 [2, 1]],

[[1, 0],
 [3, 1]]),

[[1, 1],
 [1, 2]],

[[2, 3],
 [1, 2]],

[[1, 2],
 [1, 3]],

[[1, 1],
 [2, 3]]]
```